# Ubercart Invoice converted to PDF document using ubercart theme(*) TCPDF

Tags: php, drupal-6, tcpdf, ubercart

I'm working on drupal 6 on a module that should send printable invoices in pdf to a client,  when uc order status changes to a certian status. My first thought was to use the theme function provided by ubercart and use tcpdf. Feeding tcpdf with the output html from the theming function didn't work very well. Knowing that tcpdf doesn't support all the html tags and attributes I've decided to make my own template.

My question is: Is there a module or a better way to accomplish this function?

Answer (score 0):

This module is proposed to create PDF invoices for Ubercart orders: http://drupal.org/project/uc_pdf_invoice